# Remove spaces and punctuations from Chinese string column in Python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

In order to drop duplicates from the following dataframe by `news` column, I try to remove all `spaces` and `punctuations` from this column.

```
      date                             news
0  2017-08      北京写字楼租金哪家高? 金融街、CBD、亚奥居TOP3
1  2017-08       租金一直涨,到底是谁租走了北京最贵的写字楼(附名单)
2  2017-09                 北京三季度写字楼租金继续保持平稳
3  2017-09           戴德梁行:第三季度北京写字楼市场租金保持平稳
4  2018-01  北京豪华公寓销量大涨76.5% 金融街写字楼租金创35季度新高
5  2010-11             楼市下行,高租金的商住和写字楼能不能投?
```

I have trying the following solutions:

```
df.news = df.news.apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', x)).replace(' ', '')
df.news = df.news.str.replace('[^\w\s]', '').str.strip()
```

Both generate an output with space inside the strings:

```
0         北京写字楼租金哪家高 金融街CBD亚奥居TOP3        ---> space in the phrase
1          租金一直涨到底是谁租走了北京最贵的写字楼附名单
2                 北京三季度写字楼租金继续保持平稳
3            戴德梁行第三季度北京写字楼市场租金保持平稳
4    北京豪华公寓销量大涨765 金融街写字楼租金创35季度新高  ---> space in the phrase
5               楼市下行高租金的商住和写字楼能不能投
```

The following code remove the second part of news phrases.

```
df.news = df.news.str.extract('(\w+)', expand = False)

0          北京写字楼租金哪家高
1               租金一直涨
2    北京三季度写字楼租金继续保持平稳
3                戴德梁行
4        北京豪华公寓销量大涨76
5                楼市下行
```

How can I get the expected result as follows for `news` column? Thank you.

```
0         北京写字楼租金哪家高金融街CBD亚奥居TOP3        
1          租金一直涨到底是谁租走了北京最贵的写字楼附名单
2                 北京三季度写字楼租金继续保持平稳
3            戴德梁行第三季度北京写字楼市场租金保持平稳
4    北京豪华公寓销量大涨765金融街写字楼租金创35季度新高  
5               楼市下行高租金的商住和写字楼能不能投
```

Comment: Looks like you want `df['news'] = df['news'].str.replace(r'[\W_]+', '')`

Comment: `[^\w\s]` can't match whitespace chars as it is a negated character class matching any char but a word (letter, digit, `_` + some diacritics etc.) and whitespace chars. If you remove `\s`, it will be equal to `\W` that does not match `_`, thus `[\W_]` is what you need to only keep all alphanumeric chars.

Comment: thanks, but how do you remove `spaces`? I don't understand.

Comment: `\W` matches spaces as they are non-word chars.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any tutorials on this issue to recommend?

Comment: All is explained at https://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This seems works:

```
 df.news.apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', x)).str.replace(' ', '')
```

Output:

```
0         北京写字楼租金哪家高金融街CBD亚奥居TOP3
1         租金一直涨到底是谁租走了北京最贵的写字楼附名单
2                北京三季度写字楼租金继续保持平稳
3           戴德梁行第三季度北京写字楼市场租金保持平稳
4    北京豪华公寓销量大涨765金融街写字楼租金创35季度新高
5              楼市下行高租金的商住和写字楼能不能投
```